# XLST: How to escape a select string with semi-colons in it

Tags: xslt

I am trying to have a select statement with a string that has two field names separated by a semi-colon.
Example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="&quot;Title&quot;';#'&quot;First Name&quot;"/>
```

Here we have "Title" and "First Name" separated by an escaped semi-colon.

Comment: I'm not sure what the # is doing there, buy semicolon by itself is not a cspecial character and does not need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the entire string...

```
<xsl:value-of select="'&quot;Title&quot;;&quot;First Name&quot;'"/>
```

outputs:

```
"Title";"First Name"
```